# Facing issue while rendering index value of *ngFor directive in Angular 5

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I am facing an issue while rendering index of *ngFor directive for a particular use case as follows.

Lets say we have an array of objects as

```
this.temp = [
  {name:'John',age:24,visibility:'visible',
  {name:'Kane',age:26,visibility:'hidden',
  {name:'Ross',age:28,visibility:'visible',
  {name:'Lui',age:21,visibility:'visible'
]
```

For rendering this in my app.component.html file I have html as follows

```
<div *ngFor="let user of temp; let i = index">
 <div *ngIf="user.visibility === 'visible' ">
    <div>{{i+1}}</div>
    <div>{{user.name}}</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

So as per the above array example, it renders users

```
1.John
2.Ross
3.Lui
```

Now there is a button name 'Change visibility' against each user in my UI, where in it will toggle the visibility state of user from 'hidden' to 'visible' and viceversa.

So clicking on button mentioned against John, it will set its visibility as 
hidden but the UI rendered is

```
2.Ross
3.Lui
```

My expected output is

```
1.Ross
2.Lui
```

How to make the index render properly ?

The use case here is that I cannot modify/alter my this.temp array in terms of length.Basically I need the entire array with only visiblity property changed in it as per user actions.

Please help.

Comment: can you add the function that you are using to hide the user?

Comment: Can you add the html and ts of this component?

Comment: my ts only have one method called toggleVisibility and temp array variable.

   toggleVisibility(user){
    user.visibility = user.visibilty === 'visible' ? 'hidden' :  'visible' 
   }

Answer (score 2):

you can filter array first:

```
<div *ngFor="let user of temp.filter(us => us.visibility === 'visible'); let i = index">
 <div>
    <div>{{i+1}}</div>
    <div>{{user.name}}</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

like this way, you dont analize all array items too, more efficient and desired output.

Cheers!

Comment: Angular throws error when let user of temp.filter(us => us.visibility === 'visible'); is used in html template directly.The error was 'bindings cannot contain assignment'.Hence in order to make it work I created a method getFilteredArray inside the ts file and wrote the filter logic in that method and called getFilteredArray(temp) in the html.That way it worked.Anyway thanks :)

Comment: However is it costly performance wise to call a method within the template ? need to dig more in that now

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve your required result by using [`Pipe`](https://angular.io/api?type=pipe) like this

> HTML component

```
<div *ngFor="let user of temp | visiblefilter ; let i=index">
    <span>{{i+1}} {{user.name}}</span> <button name={{user.name}} (click)="onHide($event)">Hide</button>
</div>
```

---

> PIPE

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'visiblefilter',
    pure: false
})
export class VisibleFilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(items: any[]): any {
        return items.filter(({visibility}) =>visibility=='visible');
    }
}
```

You can check here with working example **[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fnjt79)**

Comment: Thanks Narendra :)

Answer (score 0):

use a custom trackby function :

```
*ngFor="let user of temp; let i = index; trackBy: customTB"

customTB(index, item) {
  return index + ' - ' item.name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :).However i only want my index to be updated properly.How will your solution serve my use case ? Please  explain.

Comment: I won't explain it to you, I will rather redirect you to what I've found when I had the same issue : https://netbasal.com/angular-2-improve-performance-with-trackby-cc147b5104e5